# How to get the original price Product SaveBefore

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Within an **observer running before saving a product change** in the admin area, how can I get the price of the product before saving?

Using `$observer->getProduct()->getPrice()` I have the new price which has not been saved yet, but I don't know how to get the old one.

In this observer I need both prices, old and new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the purpose of the `getOrigData` method so you should be able to do:

```
$observer->getProduct()->getOrigData('price');
```

Please test that first, I know depending on the event you're observing, this does not behave as intended.

Comment: ....and you are right! 