# Magento 2 How to get the price changed product

Tags: magento2, product, price, edit

I am working with one of requirement, in my case the client wants a feature to get the price changed products (simple & configurable) product.

Explanation : During the product edit from admin, if the admin changed the product(simple & configurable) price I need to store in custom table for my functionality, is there have any good way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your support, I am looking forward to your update.

Comment: Use the reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161071/how-to-get-the-original-price-product-savebefore

Comment: Thanks @MohdShahbaz

Comment: Please upvote the comment, it will be really helpful.